# applying ng-class using true / false

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have the following two buttons that `ng-hide` and `ng-show` elements on my page.

```
<a ng-click="showimage=true" ng-class="{ 'activated': showimage}" class="button">Images</a>
<a ng-click="showimage=false" ng-class="{ 'activated': !showimage}" class="button">Details</a>
```

And to make the first button active I use:

```
$scope.showimage = true;
```

Which all works well.

My issue is that when I use these buttons the `activated` class is not applied to the active button. I would like these to work like toggles with one always being active if the other button is not.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Taylorsuk/pen/QbMxrQ?editors=101)

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr? code seems to work, so possibly problem in around code

Comment: If that's what you meant then it works fine.  Click your links and inspect the element and you'll see it's properly adding and removing the classes.

Comment: codepen seems to work, where is problem?

Comment: It's not applying the Activated class. It should look depressed

Comment: what you mean _not applying_? on click - class added to needed button, in class set only border, and border applying to pressed button - so what is wrong?

Comment: Press and hold on a button - that is the class `activated` not a border. Try and adding activated by inspecting the element and you will see.

Comment: but on `Press and hold` added class _active_, not _activated_

Comment: @Taylorsuk, i change ionic version to 1.0.0-beta.2 and now seems this all as you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwvBaR , and also set _active_ class instead _activated_

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work as is.  I created a minimalist plnkr to test with.  Perhaps you're not seeing something because of another side effect?

http://embed.plnkr.co/jnqekT3fTi77c0jg5EUx/preview

html

```
<head>
<!--....-->
  <style>
    .activated {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <a ng-click="showimage = true" ng-class="{ 'activated': showimage}" class="button">Images</a>
    <a ng-click="showimage = false" ng-class="{ 'activated': !showimage}" class="button">Details</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
}
```

Comment: It still works.  You just need to define CSS to demark what's what:   `<style>
    .activated {
       border: 1px blue solid
    }
  </style>`

Comment: I would rather not pollute my HTML with style tags.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you pollute your html. But if you want a style difference you'll have to include a style somewhere based on class. I would suggest css, but I'm crazy like that.